# how to generate Build for angular5 project with visual studio code

Tags: angular5

1. visual studio code editor.
2. angular 5  environment.
3. generate build for access project in other PC on my network.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a build of Angular 5, first you have to set **Output directory**

Open **.angular-cli.json** file from root directory.

```
"outDir": "Set your output directory here"
```

In my case, am using laravel ramework and angular together. So I have used like,

```
"outDir": "../blog/public/app"
```

Now go to the root directory of angular app and open cmd and run the below command.

```
ng build
```

If you need to mention base url,

```
ng build --base-href= <baseurl>
```

In my case,

```
ng build --base-href = http://localhost:8000/app/
```

So ,that's it. A build of your angular project created successfully inside that output directory. Hope this will help for you. Thanks :)